# Does the Enchant Magic Item spell exist anywhere in OD&D?

Tags: spells, adnd-1e, odnd

Is Enchant Magic Item (a 6th level AD&D spell) written up anywhere in the OD&D books, supplements, or Strategic Review? I am researching the difference between OD&D magic item creation and AD&D magic item creation.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

The only reference to creating Magic Items in the 1974 edition of Dungeons & Dragons is found on page 6 and 7 of Volume I (Men & Magic). In there it says

> Wizards and above may manufacture for their own use (or for sale) such
>   items as potions, scrolls, and just about anything else magical.

Looking at the level chart on page 16 of Volume I  we see that the title "Wizard" refers to a 11th level magic user.

After looking through copies of the Strategic Review and Dragon magazine from issues #1 to #20, with [help from fans of older editions](https://plus.google.com/116753362008267799901/posts/52iZkMrvMWR), I found  no reference to an Enchant Magic Item until the advent of AD&D 1st edition.

There it was made into a 6th level spell which can be cast by a 12th level wizard. In addition the 8th level permanency spell has been altered to make it a requirement for the creation of permanent magic items. This meant that in AD&D, compared to OD&D, the level of making permanent magic items has been increased from 11th level to 16th level.

Answer (score 6):

Found this in a 2009 WotC blog post:

1st Edition AD&D allowed for PCs to create magic items, but the #1 piece of advice given to the DM in this regard was, "Do not tell them how this is to be accomplished!" (DMG, pg. 116). Characters had to discover every aspect of the process through quests or trial-and-error. The challenge was so daunting for players and DMs alike that few campaigns ever attempted it.

Here is the link, as it talks about creating magic items in various editions: [Wizards article archived at the wayback machine](https://web.archive.org/web/20091206231819/http://www.wizards.com/DnD/Article.aspx?x=dnd/4alum/2009august)

So, I would guess that it if wasn't covered in the 1e version, that pre 1e it wouldn't have even been addressed.